# UIImage view - animation view logic error xCode 4.2

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to make an animation that it will changes some pictures that i have already in the app.

After searching around i found something that works pretty well for me.

Code below:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView*animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.jpg"], nil];

animationView.animationDuration = 5;
animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animationView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:animationView];
}
```

So even this works great for me, it gives me a logic error (the yellow triangle sign) and it says 
"Local declaration of 'animationView' hides instance variable"

Even tho i run the code and it does what i want it to do, i cant understand why i have this error.

Also to note that this takes place inside an UIImage that i have declared as an outlet

And one extra question: How can i add the fadein - fadeout effect ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have declared `UIImageView *animationView` as either an instance variable or a property.

You can safely remove the `UIImageView *` part in your `viewDidLoad` as there is no need to re-declare `animationView` as `UIImageView` since compiler already knows about it and that's why it gives you the warning.

So it would look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.jpg"], nil];

    animationView.animationDuration = 5;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animationView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:animationView];
}
```

Comment: this did work and resolved all logic errors with "Local declaration of 'animationView' hides instance variable" tho it did appear a new logic error  "Assining retained object to weak variable; object will released after assignment"   thanks for your help  also now its not working at all, it shows white screen on the simulator instead of having the pics changing

Comment: I have zero experience with ARC, but I'd say you have to change your property from `weak` to `strong` or something else. As for fade animation, how exactly do you want it to happen?

Comment: i want it every time an image is appearing, to fade in and then fade out and the next images appears.
lets say something like this  *fade in. image 1 appears fade out, fade in image 2 appears fade out.......  that's how i want it to work

Comment: Also i did change from weak to strong and it worked :) thank you so much! i should have thought of that before.. if u manage to resolve the fade-in fade-out thing i will own you big time!

Comment: So basically you want to create a fading slideshow? That won't be *so* easy, please start a new question and I'll answer it tomorrow if you don't get an answer by then.

Answer (score 0):

As for the fade effect you could do something like:

```
//Fade in
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[animationView setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];

//Fade out
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[animationView setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: tho i can see it does fade in - fade out , it does it only once when it loads and then it does not repeat it self while images change, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Who said anything about repeating?... If you want more complicated animations you should really check [Core Animation framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514)